# Mount Zune, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, zune, zune-software

I have a super old Zune and trying to download songs off it. I can plug it into my computer, and it shows up under devices, but doesn't appear to actually recognize it as a device.

I have downloaded and installed the Zune software.

Do I need some kind of drivers? When I plug it in, it says "Setting up new device" but then just sits there trying to load it.

This is what is shows:
[image]

Also, I am using Windows 7 (modern.ie image) as a VM using Virtual Box on Mac. If that has anything to do with what is happening.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the device still functions.  Based on the error in the screenshot it does not appear to be a functional device.

Comment: Yes, the devices turns on, plays music, etc. It appears to be fully functional.

Comment: I forgot to mention, Windows will recognize it as a new device and show a loading screen trying to connect to Windows Update but never loads.

Comment: Sounds like the USB portion of the device might not be working.

Comment: Is there somewhere I can download Zune drivers? I tried googleing but just keep finding all this spammy download software.

Comment: Windows 7 by default already has the required drivers.  Windows 7 is having trouble intializing the USB mass storage device, its specifically having problems, mounting the device.  So either your installation is configured not to allow random mass storage devices or the device isn't fully functional.  Since you would have had to specifically configure Windows not to accept random mass storage devices its much more likely the device isn't fully functional.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the help. How would I check if Windows 7 has Mass Storage devices disabled? Do you think that has something to do with it being a Virtual Machine?

Answer (score 2):

I owned and used one with W7, Similar to ipod [you have to use the "Zune software"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27163) to access it, and its a real PITA to use, no wonder the product failed. Microsoft did this to try and prevent copying of copyrighted music and video.

[How to get your songs off a Zune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xwyx-kj98nw)

Comment: I am trying to use the software though, and the above error shows up. Doesn't recognize drivers. Do you know how I can install drivers for Zune?

Comment: Evidently there is a problem with the zune and usb connection, did you try another cable?